# Node / Express / Nunjucks: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'x' in 'y'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nunjucks

Im new to the world of Nunjucks / Express and Node.

I have a routes file which is porting in the value of an input from a form field. I need to check if the value contains the expression 'gov'.

So i created the following:

```
router.get('/test/output/', function (req, res) {
  var emailAdress = req.session.data['accountEmail']
  if ('gov' in emailAdress){
    isCS = true
  }
  res.render('test/output.html',{
    'email' : emailAdress,
```

.... and so on...

And this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'gov' in 'email@email.com'
```

I understand that this is to do with objects and arrays - I just cannot find the solution - I appreciate its probably straightforward. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks for your help, nem035 ! I  used your suggestion and produced the code in my reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) only works on objects, not string primitives.

To search within a string, you can use `includes`:

```
emailAdress.includes('gov')
```

An ES5 compatible version (before `includes` existed):

```
emailAdress.indexOf('gov') !== -1
```

Or perhaps you can check if the string ends with `'gov'`:

```
emailAdress.endsWith('gov')
```

Answer (score 0):

My code ended up looking like this:

```
router.get('/test/output/', function (req, res) {

var emailAddress = req.session.data['accountEmail']
var isCS = emailAddress.includes('gov');

res.render('test/output.html',{
'email' : emailAddress,
'cs' : isCS,

'layout' : '2-0',
'h1': 'Create an account',
```

...etc. etc....